# Changing login path without modifying $HOME

Tags: shell, unix, filesystems, admin

When I start a terminal session and my shell starts I'd like it to log me in a specific directory instead of `$HOME`.

For example, I've noticed I often start a new shell session and move to `/tmp` just to clone a git repository or do some quick and temporary stuff, and I would like to be logged directly in a directory of mine like `/sandbox` or something at my shell startup rather than my `$HOME` directory.

Any of you aware of a way to achieve this without modifying my user's home directory nor adding a dumb `cd /sandbox` in my .zshrc ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `usermod -d "/tmp" your_user` should make it.

Comment: Unfortunately, usermod is linux only. Plus the -d option seems to alter the home directory of the user, which is especially the behavior I want to avoid.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to modify anything existing (.zshrc, `usermod`, etc). How would the terminal session know that it needs to start-up in a different directory? How about 2 aliases to the same machine, `defaultLogin` VS `tmpDirLogin` where (not sure how) some magic ensures that your going to tmpdir. An `expect` script? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, basically I know the behavior I want to achieve, and it seems unix systems don't have any preexisting defaults allowing it. So, yeah, will have to find something myself. expect script sounds like a good idea, will try something!

Comment: If typing `cd /sandbox` is too strenuous, you can add `alias s='cd /sandbox'` to your `.zshrc`. Then all you have to type is `s<return>` after you login.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred solution for issues like this is to use a bunch of wrapper scripts that set the desired environment properties and then `exec` an interactive shell, passing through any command line arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh

# sandbox-sh

cd /sandbox

exec bash "$@"
```

Even better, you can launch [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) instead of a single shell - any new windows you create will share the same properties as the first one. Alternatively, you may also launch a tabbed terminal emulator - any new tabs will also share the environment defined in the wrapper script.